# Short story about an angel killing a man so he doesn't commit suicide and go to hell

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I recently remembered a short story I read a very long time ago; maybe 7 years ago or more. It was given to us by our teacher so I don’t know where it comes from.

In the story a man is thinking about committing suicide. However, an angel comes and interrupts him. The man tells him his life story. The angel says that if he kills himself he will go to hell but after listening to the man's story, the angel grabs a gun and shoots him. This way the angel will go to hell and the man can go to heaven.